# Slick Slider Slideshow creates button

Tags: slider, slick.js

I have integrated several slick sliders into my website, that operates as a slideshow. They all work very well and normally except for one of them, which creates a huge hidden button halfway off the screen (see pixture). To be clear, this button is NOT created in my HTML code; rather, it is (I am assuming) created by slick as part of the animation. This is unfortunate because it causes the user to be able to scroll very off to the right where there is no actual content, just a giant invisible button. I can solve this problem by disabling horizontal scrolling, although this is treating the symptom rather than the disease, and I would rather do the latter.

For reference, here is my slick jquery slick initialisation:

```
$('.customers').slick({
dots: true,
arrows: false,
infinite: true,
speed: 600,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
autoplay: true,});
```

Thanks for your assistance!

Felix[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give position relative to the list element, so the button element won't take 100% of the screen when its with position absolute. Should fix it.